# Ruby windows installer: cannot run gem - required files not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm new to ruby gems.  I'm trying to get ruby on rails but the gem command does not work on my system.  Searched the internet and SO site, but cannot find this specific issue.  I realize this must be something basic that's wrong, but I don't know what it is...  Here are the details:

Got ruby installer from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167, install went fine.  Downloaded ruby gems from http://rubygems.org/pages/download, unzipped and in the unzipped directory ran:

ruby setup.rb

Output:

```
C:/tools/rubygems-1.8.17# ruby setup.rb
RubyGems 1.8.17 installed

== 1.8.17 / 2012-02-17

* 2 minor enhancements:

 * Add MacRuby to the list of special cases for platforms (ferrous26)
 * Add a default for where to install rubygems itself

* 3 bug fixes:

 * Fixed gem loading issue caused by dependencies not resolving.
 * Fixed umask error when stdlib is required and unresolved dependencies exist.

 * Shebang munging would only take one arg after the cmd
 * Define SUCKAGE better, ie only MRI 1.9.2
 * Propagate env-shebang to the pristine command if set for install.


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RubyGems installed the following executables:
        C:/tools/ruby/bin/e
        C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem
```

When I try running gem I get the following error:

```
C:/tools/ruby# gem env
    require: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 8: not found
    require: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 9: not found
    require: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 10: not found
    required_version: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 12: not found
    unless: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 14: not found
    abort: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 15: not found
    end: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 16: not found
    args: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 18: not found
    begin: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 20: not found
    Gem::GemRunner.new.run: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 21: not found
    rescue: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 22: not found
    exit: C:/tools/ruby/bin/gem 23: unknown operator in arithmetic expression "e.exit_code" near e.
```

I reinstalled everything and before running "ruby setup.rb" for gems, I defined GEM_HOME directory, pointing to C:/tools/ruby/gems (which I created).  That did not help in any way.  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: @uDaY Windows. Lidia, did you install 1.9? (Either 1.9.2 or 1.9.3) If so, you don't need to install RubyGems separately, it is included. You could try removing everything, installing, and then attempting to use RubyGems again.

Comment: It's the latest ruby, 1.9.3.  Good do know about RubyGems - I was confused, cause I did have gem in ruby/bin after ruby installation, however rails site says to install RubyGems separately (http://rubyonrails.org/download).  Anyhow, switching to plain old windows cmd did the trick and rails is running now too (after getting devkit separately).  :-)

Comment: @Lidia can you tell us which command prompt/console software are you using? seems to me that `gem` script is being directly interpreted by the software it runs instead of Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on Windows XP. I wanted to follow up with an explanation of / versus \ in my setup and this pointed me to the culprit: I have MKS Toolkit installed on my system and execute everything from bash, instead of windows cmd.  Once I switched to windows cmd, gem finally works fine.  A simple thing, yet took hours to debug...

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the gem binary is in your executable path.